# Load three js model into forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I try to load a three.js file (Json from rvt) into the **offline** version of the  forge viewer. How I can do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forge viewer is based on three.js. It is similar to adding mesh to the scene in native three.js context. The below are one demo extension.

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/tree/0c0db2d6426f4ff4aea1042813ed10da17c63554/src/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.MeshImporter

In this demo, the json file (Arbor Press.json) is from Inventor. It contains the definition of the geometry and material. The code of the extension will parse the json, and create mesh in the scene of Forge Viewer.

You might also need to take a look at the other extension for examples of changing material colors:

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/blob/0c0db2d6426f4ff4aea1042813ed10da17c63554/src/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Material/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Material.js

However please be aware your meshes will not be detected by the viewer selection logic, some extra work would be needed if you want that.